# 'ping git-scm.com' returns 'ping: unknown host git-scm.com'

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ping

Since a couple of days ago I'm not able to access [git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com) and when trying to `ping` to the domain:

```
ping git-scm.com
```

I get a:

```
ping: unknown host git-scm.com
```

How can I check for errors in my system's config files? I'm running [elementary OS](http://elementaryos.org/) which is based on `Ubuntu 12.04` and this appears to be the only domain I have trouble accessing.

Contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search fibertel.com.ar
```

("fibertel" is my ISP provider)

Here's the output of `dig git-scm.com +trace`:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> git-scm.com +trace
;; global options: +cmd
.           317238  IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           317238  IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           317238  IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           317238  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           317238  IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           317238  IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           317238  IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           317238  IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           317238  IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           317238  IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           317238  IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           317238  IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           317238  IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
;; Received 500 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1) in 254 ms

com.            172800  IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.
;; Received 489 bytes from 198.41.0.4#53(198.41.0.4) in 525 ms

git-scm.com.        172800  IN  NS  ns1.iwantmyname.net.
git-scm.com.        172800  IN  NS  ns2.iwantmyname.net.
git-scm.com.        172800  IN  NS  ns3.iwantmyname.net.
git-scm.com.        172800  IN  NS  ns4.iwantmyname.net.
;; Received 280 bytes from 192.42.93.30#53(192.42.93.30) in 280 ms

git-scm.com.        3600    IN  A   62.116.130.8
;; Received 45 bytes from 74.208.254.95#53(74.208.254.95) in 241 ms
```

Comment: Start by [edit]ing your question to include the contents of /etc/resolv.conf. Also, is this a general problem, or localized to only that particular host name?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling done, please see updated question.

Comment: That's interesting. If you have `dig` installed (I think it comes as a part of `bindutils`, but I'm not 100% certain about that), you can do `dig git-scm.com +trace` to emulate what your name server would do in trying to find the address record for that host. Also, I'd try clearing the cache of the resolver running on the local host. (Since DNS works for you, there's obviously *some* resolver listening on the loopback interface.) You may also want to check your firewall rules to make sure there's nothing weird going on there. It resolves for me, so it isn't an Internet-wide problem at least.

Comment: I've added the output of `dig git-scm.com +trace`, do you see anything in there that could be causing this? How do I clear my cache? I'm not sure I even have a firewall set up, but I'll check it out.

Comment: The dig output appears fine to me. If you aren't sure what software you have installed locally to do recursive name resolution, the easiest way to clear the cache might be to reboot the PC. And a little trick to try: append a `.` to the name when calling ping (`ping git-scm.com.`), and see if that changes anything. If it does, it's a search suffix problem.

Comment: I've already restarted my PC several times (this has been happening for a few days now) and adding a `.` changed nothing. I'm quite certain I did not install a firewall myself, but I'm not sure if the system has one. In any case, the domain worked just fine a couple of weeks ago, why would it stop working now?

Comment: Hi Gabriel! Your question is perfectly on topic here. In case you really don't get any answer within, say, a day, we can migrate it to [unix.SE] if you like. Just flag it again or leave me a ping.

Comment: Thank you @slhck, I'll do that if there's no answer by tomorrow afternoon. Cheers.

Comment: Well the issue seems to have gone away by itself. I guess my ISP must have been messing around with something. Regards.